# Making a DLL from a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

Is it possible making a DLL file from an existing project in visual studio C# ? instead of giving an exe , i want to supply a DLL file for another person to use my methods in his code.
i want to take the project as a whole and supply a DLL.
It is already a big project with many components , but its built not right and it will take a whole lot of time to make this code into modules, so i rather give the whole project as a dll.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 18):

Project properties -> Application tab -> Output type -> Select 'Class library' there.

Comment: Might be worth noting the DLL file will then be located in the projects `bin` folder

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep the EXE version of the project as well?

If so, create a new project that has a target of assembly in the same solution, then link in the existing .cs / .vb files.

To link:

- right-click on the project
- add existing
- select .cs file
- click "Add" dropdown arrow
- select link
- hit "Add Link" button.